# React-Native button going behind Samsung S10 camera

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native, samsung-mobile

Recently I came up with an issue where my application's tick button on the custom header has gone behind the Samsung S10 camera, I am using transparent statusbar in my application and in Samsung S10, the camera is slightly below from the top so it comes within the application viewport, I am not sure other devices, but is there a way I can detect such things and on the basis of that I can change the stylings or how to overcome such issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used StatusBar.currentHeight from 'react-native' library to fix this issue as this will provide the actual height of the statusbar rather than using any static height

Answer (score 3):

try this..

```
import { SafeAreaView, Platform } from "react-native";

render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 25 : 0}}>
          //More controls and such
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Adjust to your requirements..